# How to use code to affect the quantity of something?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ChocolateProgramByGhassan
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    String quantityString;
    double quantity;
    double price = 3.00;
    double tax = 0.75;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        price = 3.00 * quantity;
        MessageBox.Show(price.ToString());
    }

    private void domainUpDown1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        quantityString = this.domainUpDown1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        quantity = Double.Parse(quantityString);
    }

    private void buttonTax_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tax = 0.75 * quantity;
        MessageBox.Show(tax.ToString());
    }
   }
}
}
```

I wasn't being specific enough in my previous question. I just want to to know how to get quantity to affect a set number in code. I have 2 set numbers 3 and 0.75, and a button for each. For the first button I get System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: and for the second I get the desired message but the quantity does not affect the original number. What I am trying to do is enter a number and have it affect the original number stated in the code.

Comment: Can you describe your question some more detailed? I don't know what you're trying to reach with this question at the moment...

Comment: Yet I still don't understand what is it you're trying to do.

Comment: From where this quantity comes??

Comment: I really hope it's detailed enough now.

Comment: We need to know where quantity is coming from, otherwise, from all we know tax will always be te same. Do you modify "quantity"? Where and how?

Comment: This quantity is stated in the application. I am using the domainUpDown tool to state the quantity.

Comment: What are the data types for Price, Tax and Quantity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will solve the issue, but in the domainUpDown1_SelectedItemChanged event handler try setting the quantity variable with the value currently set in the DomainUpDown property. (I am assuming here that it is the quantity variable you wish to change)

Comment: Example? It is this I want to use to affect the original numbers.

Comment: When you say "this" are you referring to "quantity"? When you say "original numbers" are you referring to "tax" and "price"?

Comment: Yes "this" is referring to the tool you specified. Original numbers refer to the tax and price.

Comment: I'm getting a little confused here...in my answer I did not specify a tool. If you are referring to the DomainUpDown control/class, then that may be my mistake. It should have read "DomainUpDown property". So in your handler take the value of this property and assign it to "quantity".

Comment: I made that mistake don't worry. Please show me what you mean, I am more of a visual learner, it must be shown to me so that I understand.

Answer (score 0):

In your `SelectItemChanged` event try this code:

```
quantityString = domainUpDown1.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
quantity = Double.Parse(quantityString);
```

Istead of DomainUpDown = quantity, use `String quantityString` and `double quantity`.
Now you should have a `quantity` variable that changes anytime you change the index of your DomainUpDown. I don't know how you get the other variables, but if your problem lays here you may use this approach.

Comment: Getting there but it says that domainUpDown1 does not exist in current conext, trying to figure out how to get it defined.

Comment: "domainUpDown1" refers to the name of the variable representing the actual control. Looking at your code you may trying replacing "domainUpdateDown1.SelectedItem.ToString()" with "this.DomainUpDown.SelectedItem.ToString()".

Comment: I get this 

Error 1 'ChocolateProgramByGhassan.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'domainUpDown1' and no extension method 'domainUpDown1' accepting a first argument of type 'ChocolateProgramByGhassan.Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Ghazza\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ChocolateProgramByGhassan\ChocolateProgramByGhassan\Form1.cs 33 35 ChocolateProgramByGhassan

Comment: Don't Worry I fixed it, thank you all for your help.